# How to connect to heroku hosted server?

Tags: node.js, heroku, socket.io

I hosted server on heroku, command: **heroku local** works perfect and I can connect with client, but now I don't know how to connect to the hosted server because code: `var socket = io.connect('https://towd-server.herokuapp.com:8080');`
 does not work, only if I load it with command:**heroku local** on **localhost:8080** works.

*Thanks:)*

Comment: Do you have already a procfile?

Comment: @TheGinxx009 -- yes with code inside **web: node server.js**

Answer (score 0):

**instead of var socket = io.connect('https://towd-server.herokuapp.com:8080')**

try this one

```
var http = require('http');

var io = require('socket.io').(http);

var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
```

Comment: it's client side? because i have server side

Comment: **var http = require("http").createServer(), io = require("socket.io").listen(http);
http.listen(8080);**

Comment: it's too big to paste all

Comment: just load heroku console and typed node server.js says can't find module socket.io not sure how to install it on heroku

Comment: then on your CLI type npm install --save socket.io then reupload it to heroku

Comment: i did it but everything the same.. i have node_modules in root folder

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147064/discussion-between-tioww-and-theginxx009).